# How to start a server in debug mode in the Weblogic domain, and attach debugger in NetBeans?

Tags: debugging, netbeans, weblogic

I have a domain in **Weblogic 12c**. I had created a server in my domain, call it **MY_SERVER**. 
What I want is:

1. start this server in debug mode
2. attach NetBeans7 debugger to this server to debug my J2EE application

So I need some help to:

1. How to start a server in the domain in debug mode? (not the AdminServer!)
2. How to attach the debugger to this server in NetBeans?
3. How can I reach the debug port? Where can I find it?

I tried to add these arguments to **MY_SERVER --> ServerStart --> Arguments**:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,suspend=n,transport=dt_socket,address=8787
```

but if I started the server after this setup, server was crashed:

```
Starting WLS with line:
c:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_4\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=ewi-upc-server -Djava.security.policy=c:\SERVERS\wls12120\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=C:\Domains\domain\servers\ewi-upc-server\data\nodemanager\boot.properties -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=false -Dweblogic.ReverseDNSAllowed=false -Dlog4j.configuration=file:c:/ATOLL_HOME/WORKFLOW/config/log4j.xml -Dlog4j.debug=true -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,suspend=n,transport=dt_socket,address=8787 -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=c:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_4\jre\lib\endorsed;c:\SERVERS\wls12120\oracle_common\modules\endorsed  -da -Dwls.home=c:\SERVERS\wls12120\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=c:\SERVERS\wls12120\wlserver\server   -Dweblogic.management.server=http://10.112.238.81:7001   weblogic.Server
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add exactly the same arguments to: **MY_SERVER --> ServerStart --> Arguments**:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=none -Xrunjdwp:server=y,suspend=n,transport=dt_socket,address=8787
```